# What does the @ManagedNotification annotation do?

Tags: java, spring, jmx

There is a lot of code for this SSCCE, however I've added this on [github](https://github.com/selenium34/jmx-example) to make it easier to interact with.

I'm attempting to wrap my head around this annotation, but I can't seem to figure out its use. I've created a sample application. I'm able to create the MBean, monitor it, and connect to my local MBean server to modify the application while running, but see no real use for @ManagedNotification and @ManagedNotifications.

I can remove the ManagedNotifications on my class, and still receive the notifications. The only difference is that I don't see the description of the Notificaiton, however so long as your messages are good, I don't see the need for this annotation. Is there anything extra I'm missing? The javadocs on it state it is to be used on a method, but the target for @ManagedNotifications and @ManagedNotification is limited to type only. Is there more to this annotation than I am seeing?